add_image_size() parameter four ($crop = true) is ignored: the_post_thumbnail() returns scaled image(s) instead of hard cropped
Good Day!
I am trying to achieve hard cropping of thumbnails in a custom WordPress theme. In functions.php I have added add_image_size('blog-large', 860, 484, true);. Thus, the fourth parameter ($crop=true) should hard crop any image larger than 860x484 pixels to that size. My test image is 1920x1200 pixels. The 'blog-large' is confirmed as an image size in the "regenerate thumbnail plugin" I use and the plugin's frontend says it regenerates the images without issues. The problem is that the image is rendered in the browser (Firefox on Windows 11) as 774 x 484, not 860x484. In other words it seems to scale the image down to 484 in height, retaining the image aspect ratio of 1.6 (774/484 ≈ 1.6 <=> 1920/1200 ≈ 1.6).
I am outputing the image through the WP function the_post_thumbnail(). My current configuration is simply: if (has_post_thumbnail()){ the_post_thumbnail('blog-large'); }.
I have tried:

Removing all images from the media library, then inserting two images larger than 860x484, several times.
Regenerated new post thumbnails, several times.
Tested the two above in different orders.
added the add_image_size() code inside a function initiated right afterwards with an add_action('after_setup_theme', 'df_theme_support') hook.
Checked for any CSS that might affect the image - turned off every style for the  element available in the Inspector. I have also turned off all styling for parent element(s) such as flex etc. I have also moved around the code inside the loop, going inside different elements (<article>, <main>, <div>, etc.).
Added: Also checked for PHP errors. Nothing is outputed in the debug.log file.
Added: I have also deactivated all the seven (7) plugins and tried again with no change.
Added: Check in wp-content/uploads/2024/12 reveals that only the original files are there despite use of Regenerate Thumbnails plugin AND re-upload of image(s).

The outputed image is inside the Wordpress loop.
Single.php:
              if(have_posts()) {
                while(have_posts()) {
                  the_post();
                  get_template_part('template-parts/content', 'article');
                }
              }

content-article.php (Updated php/HTML 2024-12-10 14:12):
<?php 
 if (has_post_thumbnail()):?>
      <img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url('blog-large');?>">
<?php endif;?>

functions.php:
<?php

function df_theme_support() {
  //Adds dynamic title tag support
  add_theme_support('title-tag');
  add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');
  add_theme_support('widgets');
  add_post_type_support('page', 'excerpt');
}
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'df_theme_support');

// Custom Image Sizes
add_image_size('blog-large', 860, 484, true);
//true crops it
// add_image_size('blog-small', 300, 200, true); //random size

// load css into the website's front-end (admin and login-page also possible). See guide.
function df_register_styles() {
  // mt_rand(20,9999)
  $version = wp_get_theme()->get('Version');
  wp_enqueue_style('style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array(), $version, 'all');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'df_register_styles');


function df_register_scripts() {
  //footer loaded
  wp_enqueue_script('main', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/main.js', array(), '1.0', true);
  //header loaded
  wp_enqueue_script('ham-navbar', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/ham-navbar.js', array(), '1.0', false);
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'df_register_scripts');


function df_widget_areas(){
  register_sidebar(
    array(
      'name' => 'Sidopanel 1',
      'id' => 'sidebar-primary',
      'description' => 'Primär sidopanel (sidebar widget area)',
      'before_sidebar' => '',
      'after_sidebar' => '',
      'before_widget' => '<section class="sect generic-sidebar-section">',
      'after_widget' => '</section>',
      'before_title' => '<h3 class="aside-section-h3">',
      'after_title' => '</h3>'
    )
  );
  register_sidebar(
    //Mobile/tablet ham ("aside") navigation search widget.
    array(
      'name' => 'Sökfunktion för sidomeny (ham)',
      'id' => 'searchfunction-sidemenu',
      'description' => '',
      'before_sidebar' => '',
      'after_sidebar' => '',
      'before_widget' => '',
      'after_widget' => '',
      'before_title' => '',
      'after_title' => ''
    )
  );
}
add_action('widgets_init', 'df_widget_areas');

The link to the image when testing out this (the one 1920x1280): https://pixabay.com/sv/photos/fiske-vietnam-fiskare-provins-9246364/
The HTML  src attribute value retrieved from the browser:
http://localhost/test-page/wp-content/uploads/2024/12/fishing-9246364_1920.jpg
The HTML of (1) thumbnail (featured image) of a post and (2) another image inserted into a page: (1) <img src="http://localhost/test-site/wp-content/uploads/2024/12/fishing-9246364_1920.jpg"> (2) <img fetchpriority="high" decoding="async" aria-describedby="caption-attachment-166" class="size-full wp-image-166" src="http://localhost/test-site/wp-content/uploads/2024/12/christmas-8453176s_1920.jpg" alt="qwq" width="1920" height="1302">
Greatful for any tips. Have a good day. With regards//Daniel

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
